# DataFormatterStyle has no member .mediumStyle

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, nsdateformatter

In closure I want to set styles for date and time,

```
private let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .mediumStyle
    formatter.timeStyle = .shortStyle
    return formatter
}()
```

but getting such error

```
Type 'DataFormatterStyle has no member .mediumStyle'
```

Previously with NSDateFormatter worked fine

Comment: which swift are you using? try capitalized .MediumStyle for Swift 2.3

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Look at the documentation for `DateFormatter.Style`. Your code should be:

```
private let dateFormatter: DateFormatter = {
    let formatter = DateFormatter()
    formatter.dateStyle = .medium
    formatter.timeStyle = .short
    return formatter
}()
```

Just about everything changed in Swift 3.

Comment: Doesn't look like they've updated the doc for DateFormatter yet to reflect this: https://developer.apple.com/reference/foundation/dateformatter